# Spring JPA - Handle DB/Repo exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-data-jpa

I have a SpringBoot app which uses spring data `CrudRepository` to persist messages. 
It is important for the app to not to loose messages when there is **DB server side exception**.

> e.g.  DB server unreachable or DB instance facing memory issues etc.

Hence I want to handle them particularly and retry till DB server side issue is 
resolved.
I came across this article which explains `Exception` classes thrown by Spring JPA
https://danielkvist.net/code/spring-data-crudrepository-exceptions
which summarises `Exception` hierarchy for Spring JPA. Hence I applied following `Exception` handling logic.

```
saveMessages (List<Message> messages)
{
    try {
        crudRepo.saveAll(messages);
    } catch (NonTransientDataAccessException | TransientDataAccessException e) {
      // throw custom retryable exception for the service to retry
      throw new CustomRetryableException(e);
    }
}
```

When the code was executed in production above logic failed, since there were different kinds of exceptions being thrown.
e.g. when DB server was down `CannotCreateTransactionException` was thrown or when DB server got restarted in between request `TransactionSystemException` was thrown.
So I guess I missed handling sub classes of `TransactionException`

Questions:

1. What is the best way to handle sub classes of `TransactionException`? (In the context I mentioned in the begining)
2. Are there any other additional Exceptions (other than `DataAccessException` and  `TransactionException` that I should handle ?

Answer (score 0):

you could catch the parent class of your exceptions, but if you want to catch/deal with the exceptions in the DAO/service I would just catch the RuntimeException

```
try {
    crudRepo.saveAll(messages);
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
  // add log here!

  throw new CustomRetryableException(e);
}
```

Another approach is to use a generic `ExceptionHandler` to define this logic in a separate class (you can also define different handlers for different exceptions)

```
 @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> genericHandler(HttpServletRequest request, RuntimeException ex) {
```

More info and examples [here](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. But I should not handle every Runtime exception. e.g. ScriptExecutionException which can occur due to malformed SQL. Now there is no point of retry coz DB can't do much here, since it is client side issue. I specifically want to catch DB side exceptions. I think by handling NonTransientDataAccessException |, TransientDataAccessException and TransactionException I should be good. But wanted to confirm.